# How to read the Json file from Resources

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am developping Spring Java application with Maven. I need to read a .json file, that is situated in Resources folder in my project, and than return it by Controller again as a .json file. How can I do that? I am a beginner...

Comment: Finally I used : FileReader reader = new FileReader("classpath:myfile") ; JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader); return jsonObject; It works well, I have only problems with local characters in json file.

Comment: See [java.io.FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html): "_The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding [is] appropriate. To specify the[...] value[..] yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream._"

Answer (score 2):

Resourece folder is in your class path. Any file which is in your class path , you can read through this.

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourFile.json");
```

you can read by using `getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 0):

If you access to file in Spring bean you could also use @Value annotation like that (It work only in spring beans)

```java
@Value("classpath:data/resource-data.txt")
Resource resourceFile;
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access#2-using-value